# Error (infinite looping or something else) causing my code to stop running in the shell partway through

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Although I cannot tell exactly what the cause is, something in my code is causing it to stop running partway through, leaving the shell in a state where I can click on a line, type, press enter etc. but I am given no reaction by the shell itself.

The full code is as follows:

```
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps


background = "background.png"
target = input("Please enter the name of your image (including file type)")
targetImage = Image.open(target)
background = Image.open(background)
area = targetImage.size 
backArea = background.size
area = (round(area[0] / 500), round(area[1] / 500))
backArea = (round(backArea[0] / 100), round(backArea[1] / 100))
targetImage = targetImage.resize(area)
background = background.resize(backArea)
size = area[0] * area[1]
targetWidth = area[0]
targetLength = area[1]

targetCoords = []


def analyser():
    pixelOne = 1
    pixelTwo = 1
    completedSearch = 0


    while completedSearch != size:
        while pixelOne != targetWidth:
            while pixelTwo != targetLength:
                targetCoords.append((pixelOne, pixelTwo))
                pixelTwo = pixelTwo + 1
                completedSearch = completedSearch + 1
            pixelTwo = 1
            pixelOne = pixelOne + 1


    colouredCoordsSum = []
    largerColouredCoordsSum = []
    smallerColouredCoordsSum = []
    flatTargetCoords = [x for sets in targetCoords for x in sets]
    coordLength = len(flatTargetCoords) - 1
    for i in range(0, coordLength, 2):
        firstnum = flatTargetCoords[i]
        secondnum = flatTargetCoords[i+1]
        sumnum = firstnum + secondnum
        if firstNum > secondNum:
            largerColouredCoordsSum.append("(",firstNum,", ",secondNum,"), (",sumnum,")")
        else:
            smallerColouredCoordsSum.append("(",firstNum,", ",secondNum,")")
        colouredCoordsSum.append(sumnum)

    global topLeft
    global bottomRight
    global topRight
    global bottomLeft
    topLeft = min(smallerColouredCoordsSum)
    bottomRight = max(largerColouredCoordsSum)
    topRight = topLeft + (area[0] - 1)
    bottomLeft = bottomRight - (area[1] - 1)


analyser()
print(topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight)
```

The area of the code I think is the problem is the contents of the first while loop:

```
while completedSearch != size:
        while pixelOne != targetWidth:
            while pixelTwo != targetLength:
                targetCoords.append((pixelOne, pixelTwo))
                pixelTwo = pixelTwo + 1
                completedSearch = completedSearch + 1
            pixelTwo = 1
            pixelOne = pixelOne + 1
```

That being said, there may be other errors that are causing this. I haven't been able to progress in removing errors past this point as the code doesn't fully run in the shell in this state. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: When I run the code, I am given the input prompt, but after typing the file name and pressing enter, I don't see anything run, nor do I see the '>>>' at the next line, but I can click between empty lines, type, and press enter on those lines, but the shell doesn't react to anything I type into it in that state. It should print the co-ordinates of each corner to the shell when complete, but it does not occur.

Comment: it should be equivalent, but in case, it might be safer to say while completedSearch < size

Comment: *How* does it stop? Does it give you an exception? For some input, what is the expected *and* actual output? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And of course, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I also recommend you read all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/, to learn *some* reasons your question is getting down-voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while completedSearch != size:
    while pixelOne != targetWidth:
        while pixelTwo != targetLength:
            targetCoords.append((pixelOne, pixelTwo))
            pixelTwo = pixelTwo + 1
            completedSearch = completedSearch + 1
        pixelTwo = 1
        pixelOne = pixelOne + 1
```

When this loop begins, if `completedSearch` is larger than `size`, or `pixelOne` is larger than `targetWidth`, or `pixelTwo` is larger than `targetLength`, it will never exit.

Comment: completedSearch is set to 0 before the while loop runs, and pixelOne or pixelTwo cannot be larger than the targets set for them unless the size of the image is 1x1 px, because both are set to 1 before the while loop runs.

Comment: yes, but to get to the full size, you want your loop to happen when = to width or length, or else you never get the whole search completed. You could get away with != for the top (though why mess, just make it <), but the ineer 2 should both be <=

Comment: The moral of the story is be as general as you can with your comparisons, yes you want the loop to end when `completedSearch == size` but you also would want it to not run if `completedSearch > size`, therefore your condition should be `while completedSearch < size`